# Код клавиши Enter в SWT

Tags: eclipse, java, swt

Здравствуйте. Сегодня искал в SWT код Enter, но ничего подобного в классе SWT (так и называется; там объявлены константы, отвечающие в том числе за кейкоды) не нашёл, хотя остальные присутствуют. Тогда поймал отладчиком и вписал литералы. Затем прошёлся поиском по этому классу и откопал код Enter'а, расположенного на кейпаде. Код обычного Enter'а не нашёл. Вопрос: поскольку SWT завязан на ось, может ли быть такое, что этот слушатель, если проект запустят на другой платформе, на обычный Enter реагировать не будет?

Comment: @Артём Быков, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может быть [SWT.CR](http://SWT.CR), по аналогии с SWT.KEYPAD_CR

Comment: Точно, так и есть, спасибо=)
Там как раз в комменте к константе написано про возврат каретки, чем энтер в принципе и занимается (carriage return)